# Is this query valid? I want to update a table, joining two different tables, and to display the data to two different forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, database

So, what I'm trying to do is: I've got pageA.php to get the user's name, surname and question saved to the DB (With forms and Jquery). I'm displaying those questions in another table (Used by the "Technical Team" to answer those questions. I want to as soon as I answer, not to show the question in the technical team page anymore, and to display the answer in pageA.php. I've tried several things but nothing quite right yet.

Here's the sql query that I'm not too sure about:

```
    $Ssql = "UPDATE questions SET Qstatus=1 
    WHERE answers.customerName=users.name 
    FROM users, answers 
    INNER JOIN users 
    ON answers.userID=users.userID;";
```

What I'm trying to do is, change the Qstatus to 1 when the question is answered. 0 = Not answered, 1 = Answered. First Page to ask for details.

[image: Form to get the Customer's details]

[image: TextBox to get the Customer's question]

[image: Gif shown to the user while the technical team answer the question]

[image: Question available to answer]

Here's the code I'm using ATM to insert the data to the DB and to update if the question was answered.

```
        if ($_POST) 
{
    $staffName = test_input($_POST['staffName']);  
    $customerName = test_input($_POST['customerName']);
    $answer = test_input($_POST['answer']);

    try 
    {
        $host = '127.0.0.1';
        $dbname = 'webapp';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = '';
        $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    } 

    catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
        echo "An error occurred saving your details. Please, try again!";
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `answers` (`staffName`, `customerName`, `answer`) VALUES (?,?,?);";
    $sth = $DBH->prepare($sql);

    $sth->bindParam(1, $staffName, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindParam(2, $customerName, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindParam(3, $answer, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $sth->execute();

    $Ssql = "UPDATE questions SET Qstatus=1 WHERE answers.customerName=users.name FROM users, answers INNER JOIN users ON answers.userID=users.userID;";
    $Ssth = $DBH->prepare($Ssql);
    $Ssth->execute();
}
```

What I'm struggling with is how to change the Qstatus to 1, when the question was answered, and how to trigger to show a table in pageA.php with all answers when there's answers available. Hope it's understandable and all help possible is greatly appreciated! THANK YOU!!

Comment: You could try running the query and immediately see that there are syntax errors.  You put a lot of effort into the question; trying it would be much easier.

Comment: Hi Gordon. Like I mentioned before, I tried but it's not working like I'd like to. That's why I'm asking here if somebody else can spot the error or a better way to do it. If I'd knew how to do it or what's wrong with it, I woulnd't be asking for help, would I? Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In your query have some issue so i modified.

```
 $Ssql = "UPDATE questions,users,answers          
         SET Qstatus=1 
         WHERE answers.customerName=users.name   
         AND answers.userID=users.userID;";
```

Here  may be add one conditon also. which is maintain question's anwser `one-to-many` relation. I dont know your datastructure of table so i cant add it here